# Ubuntu Server installation fails on Thinkpad 400 laptop

Tags: server, system-installation, kernel, laptop

Would like to learn more about Ubuntu Server, but have been failing while installing. Any help is appreciated!

1. Is it a good idea to install Ubuntu server on a old laptop like a Thinkpad 400 for learning purpose?
2. if so, can anyone please help
   figure out why I keep failing while installing ? I have attached the
   syslog.Thank you so much in advance.
3. Can you also share if you know there installation step guide for it.

```
    Apr 16 17:10:18 in-target:   Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:10:18 in-target: Get:9 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 amd64 4.8.0.36.8 [2,472 B]
    Apr 16 17:10:18 in-target: Get:10 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.8.0-36 all 4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1 [10.3 MB]
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: Get:11 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic amd64 4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1 [823 kB]
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: Get:12 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 amd64 4.8.0.36.8 [2,448 B]
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: Get:13 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 amd64 4.8.0.36.8 [1,802 B]
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic_4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic_4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:10:19 in-target: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: The following additional packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target:   linux-headers-4.8.0-36 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: The following NEW packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target:   linux-headers-4.8.0-36 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target:   linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Need to get 0 B/11.1 MB of archives.
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: After this operation, 80.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Get:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.8.0-36 all 4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1 [10.3 MB]
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Get:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic amd64 4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1 [823 kB]
    Apr 16 17:10:20 in-target: Get:3 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 amd64 4.8.0.36.8 [2,448 B]
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.8.0-36.^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... ^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 5%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 10%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 15%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 20%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 25%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 30%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 35%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 40%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 45%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 50%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 55%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 60%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 65%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 70%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 75%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 80%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 85%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 90%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 95%^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: (Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: 10458 files and directories currently installed.)^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.8.0-36_4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1_all.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:21 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-4.8.0-36 (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:31 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic.^M
    Apr 16 17:10:31 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic_4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:31 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:33 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04.^M
    Apr 16 17:10:33 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04_4.8.0.36.8_amd64.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:33 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.36.8) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:34 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-36 (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:34 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic (4.8.0-36.36~16.04.1) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:34 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (4.8.0.36.8) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:10:35 base-installer: error: exiting on error base-installer/kernel/failed-install
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): 0
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: (process:21671): unknown udeb squashfs-modules
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: WARNING **: Configuring 'live-installer' failed with error code 1
    Apr 16 17:12:28 main-menu[1109]: WARNING **: Menu item 'live-installer' failed.
    Apr 16 17:12:30 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from 'high' to 'medium'
    Apr 16 17:12:30 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
    Apr 16 17:12:31 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
    Apr 16 17:12:32 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
    Apr 16 17:12:32 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Menu item 'live-installer' selected
    Apr 16 17:12:32 base-installer: warning: attempting to install to unclean target
    Apr 16 17:12:33 base-installer: info: Using squashfs support for /cdrom/install/filesystem.squashfs
    Apr 16 17:12:33 anna-install: Installing squashfs-modules
    Apr 16 17:12:39 live-installer: WARNING: no live-config script matching /target/lib/live/config/*-ssl-cert !
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Using CD-ROM mount point /media/cdrom/
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Identifying... [baf52e5369ed154366c2a297e784a7e4-2]
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Scanning disc for index files...
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Found 2 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes and 1 signatures
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: This disc is called: 
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: 'Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)'
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Copying package lists...
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: gpgv: Signature made Wed Feb 15 20:36:12 2017 UTC using RSA key ID EFE21092
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) "
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: ^MReading Package Indexes... 0%^M
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: ^MReading Package Indexes... Done^M
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Writing new source list
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Source list entries for this disc are:
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)]/ xenial main restricted
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial InRelease
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial Release
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:12:39 base-installer: 
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: locales is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu5).
    Apr 16 17:12:40 in-target: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:12:40 localechooser: Generating locales (this might take a while)...
    Apr 16 17:12:40 localechooser:   en_US.UTF-8
    Apr 16 17:12:40 localechooser: ...
    Apr 16 17:12:41 localechooser:  done
    Apr 16 17:12:41 localechooser: Generation complete.
    Apr 16 17:12:41 localechooser: Generating locales (this might take a while)...
    Apr 16 17:12:41 localechooser:   en_US.UTF-8
    Apr 16 17:12:41 localechooser: ...
    Apr 16 17:12:42 localechooser:  done
    Apr 16 17:12:42 localechooser: Generation complete.
    Apr 16 17:12:45 live-installer: update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
    Apr 16 17:12:45 live-installer: update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
    Apr 16 17:12:45 live-installer: update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Apr 16 17:12:46 live-installer: Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
    Apr 16 17:12:47 live-installer: update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Apr 16 17:12:47 live-installer: Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-signed-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-generic-hwe-16.04 usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-virtual usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-signed-image-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-virtual usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: kernel linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic usable on amd64
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: Found kernels 'linux-signed-generic,linux-generic-hwe-16.04,linux-generic,linux-virtual,linux-signed-image-generic,linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic,linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic,linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04,linux-image-generic,linux-image-virtual,linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic,linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic,linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic'
    Apr 16 17:12:48 base-installer: info: preseeded/current kernel: linux-generic-hwe-16.04
    Apr 16 17:12:54 base-installer: info: Using kernel 'linux-generic'
    Apr 16 17:12:54 base-installer: warning: Failed to get debconf answer 'base-installer/kernel/linux/initrd'.
    Apr 16 17:12:54 base-installer: info: Setting do_initrd='yes'.
    Apr 16 17:12:54 base-installer: info: Setting link_in_boot='no'.
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: busybox-initramfs is already the newest version (1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1).
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: initramfs-tools is already the newest version (0.122ubuntu8.8).
    Apr 16 17:12:55 in-target: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: The following additional packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   crda iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-headers-4.4.0-62
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-image-generic wireless-regdb
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Suggested packages:
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Recommended packages:
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | grub-efi-ia32 | grub | lilo thermald
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: The following NEW packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   crda iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target:   linux-image-generic wireless-regdb
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: 0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Need to get 0 B/106 MB of archives.
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: After this operation, 453 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 libnl-3-200 amd64 3.2.27-1 [52.1 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 libnl-genl-3-200 amd64 3.2.27-1 [11.2 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:3 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 wireless-regdb all 2015.07.20-1ubuntu1 [9,058 B]
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:4 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 iw amd64 3.17-1 [63.5 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:5 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 crda amd64 3.13-1 [60.5 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:00 in-target: Get:6 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.157.8 [37.7 MB]
    Apr 16 17:13:01 in-target: Get:7 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83 [21.3 MB]
    Apr 16 17:13:03 in-target: Err:7 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83
    Apr 16 17:13:03 in-target:   Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:13:03 in-target: Get:8 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83 [36.3 MB]
    Apr 16 17:13:07 in-target: Err:8 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83
    Apr 16 17:13:07 in-target:   Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:13:07 in-target: Get:9 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.4.0.62.65 [2,290 B]
    Apr 16 17:13:07 in-target: Get:10 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-62 all 4.4.0-62.83 [9,907 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Get:11 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83 [773 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Get:12 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.4.0.62.65 [2,256 B]
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Get:13 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 4.4.0.62.65 [1,784 B]
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: E
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: : Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8)/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Reading package lists...
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Building dependency tree...
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: 
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Reading state information...
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: The following additional packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target:   linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: The following NEW packages will be installed:
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target:   linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-generic
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Need to get 0 B/10.7 MB of archives.
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: After this operation, 77.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Apr 16 17:13:08 in-target: Get:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-62 all 4.4.0-62.83 [9,907 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: Get:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic amd64 4.4.0-62.83 [773 kB]
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: Get:3 cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.8) xenial/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.4.0.62.65 [2,256 B]
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-62.^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... ^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 55%^M(Reading database ... 60%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 65%^M(Reading database ... 70%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 75%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 80%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 85%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 90%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 95%^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: (Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 10458 files and directories currently installed.)
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: ^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-62_4.4.0-62.83_all.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:09 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-62 (4.4.0-62.83) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:17 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic.^M
    Apr 16 17:13:17 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:17 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic (4.4.0-62.83) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:19 in-target: Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic.^M
    Apr 16 17:13:19 in-target: Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.4.0.62.65_amd64.deb ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:19 in-target: Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.62.65) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:19 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-62 (4.4.0-62.83) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:20 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic (4.4.0-62.83) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:20 in-target: Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.62.65) ...^M
    Apr 16 17:13:21 base-installer: error: exiting on error base-installer/kernel/failed-install
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): 0
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: (process:23509): unknown udeb squashfs-modules
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: WARNING **: Configuring 'live-installer' failed with error code 1
    Apr 16 17:13:32 main-menu[1109]: WARNING **: Menu item 'live-installer' failed.
    Apr 16 17:13:33 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from 'medium' to 'low'
    Apr 16 17:13:33 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to low
    Apr 16 17:13:34 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
    Apr 16 17:13:38 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
    Apr 16 17:13:38 main-menu[1109]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

Comment: have you tried a regular install, just to see the result?